# How to check if model already exists in get it before registering?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

I have been using get_it package a lot lately and it has been pretty useful. However sometimes i need to check if a model has been registered before as a singleton before registering. Otherwise i will get an exception saying this model is already registered. Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/fluttercommunity/get_it#testing-if-a-singleton-is-already-registered

Comment: @Nuts thanks alot it must be a new feature because i looked at the docs in the past and found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need to check this logic. Because if the structure is a singleton, you have to register when the application runs. However, they thought to test this feature, you can try the isRegistered function. You can view the readme file.